# How to load urls into Scrapy one by one

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a crawler that needs to crawl over 5 million urls.Currently I'm using the following way that loads all the urls from a file into start_urls list, which I found took too much memory.

```
self.start_urls = get_list_from_file(file_path)
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way that I can load the urls into memory one by one, so I can keep the memory cost low.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use [start_requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method on the spider. For example:

```
def start_requests(self):
    reader = csv.reader(open('urls.csv'))
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0]
        yield Request(url=url)
```

Plus, it would be a good idea to make your `get_list_from_file` function to work as a generator.

Hope that helps.